# How to get the all the predecessors of a number in a SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, select

How can I get all the predecessors of a number in a SQL select statement?

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN tb2.status = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS num_sales
FROM 
    table1 AS tb1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 AS tb2 ON tb1.id = tb2.id_sales
```

I get this result:

| num_sales |
| --- |
| 7 |
| 5 |
| 4 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

I want

| num_sales | predecessors |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 |
| 5 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
| 4 | 1,2,3,4 |
| 3 | 1,2,3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 |  |

HELP!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you included matching input tables at least the primary/secondary keys.  Do you need need to join with table1 in your example?  Are predecessors just num_sales down to 1, or are they attributes of table2?

Comment: If you just want to get a string of all integers 1,2,...n for a given n, I would probably write a small function for this. This can also be done with SQL (e.g. with a recursive query), but a function seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Standard SQL, you could use `listagg()`:

```
select mynumber,
       (select listagg(t2.mynumber, ',') within group (order by t2.mynumber)
        from mytable t2
        where t2.mynumber <= t.mynumber
       ) as predecessors
from mytable t;
```

Similar functionality exists is most databases, but the exact details for string aggregation often very by database.

EDIT:

In Postgres, you would use `generate_series()`:

```
select mynumber,
       (select string_agg(gs.n, ',' order by gs.n desc)
        from generate_series(1, t.mynumber, 1) gs(n)
       ) as predecessors
from mytable t;
```

Comment: According to the expected result in table, the expected values are all numbers 1... mynumber. in your answer you are not retrieving 2,6 if mynumber is 7.